# How to do fine tuning on TFlite model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, transfer-learning

I would like to fine tune a model on my own data. However the model is distributed by tflite format. Is there anyway to extract the model architecture and parameters out of the tflite file?

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to convert the TFLite file to another format, and import into a deep learning framework that supports training.

Something like ONNX, using [tflite2onnx](https://pypi.org/project/tflite2onnx/), and then import into a framework of your choice.  Not all frameworks can import from ONNX (e.g. PyTorch).  I believe you can train with ONNXRuntime, and MXNet.  Unsure if you can train using TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you need. But if you want to know the exact architecture of your model you can use [neutron](https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/) to find out.
You will get something like the this : [image]

And for your information TensorFlow Lite is not meant to be finetuned. You need to finetune a classic TensorFlow model and then convert it to TensorFlow Lite.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to me to understand the architecture of the model. The model I got is in the format of tflite, my original question was if there is a way to load or convert tflite into tensorflow as a tensorflow model so I can fine tune certain layers on my own data

Comment: Maybe the answer of @Prunus can help you to convert into TensorFlow. I've never tested it myself. Or now that you have the architecture you can build it yourself on TensorFlow directly.